# How to recognise if user clicked out of text input and run php in that event

Tags: php, javascript, click, execute

How can I use javascript to check, if the user clicks out of my text input `class = "foo"`, and then, if the user has done so, execute a php file.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Do you want to redirect the user to the PHP page or simply execute it without the user knowing?

Comment: @Xeon06 How can I possibly try to do that, without knowing how?

Comment: Actually here we prefer when people try and learn instead of just getting code from others. If you don't know JavaScript, then you should learn it before asking questions relating to it. If you do, you should have a simple idea of how to start.

Comment: @Xeon06 To be honest, I have tried pretty hard, but how would I be able to find this without some help by experts???

Comment: It's a completely valid question. Not sure why it's being voted down. SO rules don't require OPs to post all the code they have already tried and a full history of the hard work they have done up to this point trying to solve the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to go about doing this, is to use jQuery.

First, include jQuery in your `<head></head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add in the following Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.foo').blur(function(){
    $.ajax('myScript.php');
  });
});
```

This will setup the `input` (who's class is `foo`) to use ajax to run `myScript.php` whenever someone clicks out of it, which in development terms is called *blurring*.

Comment: Two points to make: 1) This is in jQuery, not vanilla JS (obvious, but the OP should be told) and 2) You give absolutely no explanation whatsoever. Please rectify.

Comment: Vanilla js: I got to `document.getElementsByT...` then I realized I would have to write up a mini DOM/AJAX framework and stopped.

Comment: @Xeon06 Good point. At any rate, your question has been much improved. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with plain javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function runAjax(){
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {                        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","fooscript.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form>
    <input name="vorname" type="text" onblur="runAjax()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it's a good idea to use a javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). I've stolen this example from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).